# Tabela dinâmica MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou precisando retornar o resultado da procedure, coloquei um valor fixo apenas para realizar meus testes porem ele terá uma entrada digitada, em datepick.
Porem não consigo criar a lista para as colunas.

Segue o trecho do código:

```
public string dtaTotal(string dtaini, string dtafinal)
    {

       List<string> dtatot = new List<string>();

       var result = "'" + dtaini + "'" + "," + "'" + dtafinal + "'";

       return result;
    }

    private List<Campanha> BuscaCampanhas()
    {
       using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("exec pr_DashBrokerCampanhas '01-09-2018', '10-09-2018'", DBConnection))
       {
           DBConnection.Open();
           using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
           {
               List<Campanha> _listCampanhas = new List<Campanha>();

                  while (reader.Read())
                  {
                      _listCampanhas.Add(

                          new Campanha
                          {
                              DescCampanha = reader["DescCampanha"].ToString(),
                              Total = reader["Total"].ToString(),
                              Columns = dtaTotal()
                          }
                      );
                  }

               DBConnection.Close();
               return _listCampanhas;

           }
       }
    }
```

**Classe Campanha:**

```
public class Campanha
{
    public string DescCampanha { get; set; }
    public string Total { get; set; }
    public List<string> Columns { get; set; }
}

public class Dashboard
{
    public List<Envio> Envios { get; set; }
    public List<Broker> Brokers { get; set; }
    public List<Campanha> Campanhas { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller da index:**

```
        var DashboardContent = new Dashboard();

        DashboardContent.Envios = BuscaTodosEnvios();
        DashboardContent.Brokers = BuscaBrokers();
        DashboardContent.Campanhas = BuscaCampanhas();

        return View(DashboardContent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente você precisa rever sua função `dtaTotal(string dtaini, string dtafinal)`, pois ela espera dois parâmetros que não foram passados quando chamou ela no método `BuscaCampanhas()`. E, além disso, o método `dtaTotal` deveria retornar uma `List<string>` e não está fazendo isso.

Quanto a receber o valor do campo DatePicker na Controller, existem várias maneiras de se fazer isso. A mais simples é através da **Model DashboardContent** que você está enviando da **Controller** para a **View**.

Veja [neste artigo](http://www.macoratti.net/15/11/mvc_caldt1.htm) algo parecido que poderá orientá-lo na sua implementação: